# Desk clock scrollable tab bar - what's it called?

Tags: java, android, widget

I'd like to find some examples, of how to implement a scrollable tab bar as found in the htc's desk clock app as seen below

[image: Widget]

Not sure what I should be looking for though? What's it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Listview` is not an option, as it does not support horizontal scrolling. I would make it based on a `HorizontalScrollView`. See the [manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)